# correct a bad generated link using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a system that dynamically generates links. but the html links are displayed like this :

```
<a href="<a href=&quot;/page-example&quot;>Page Example</a>">Page Example</a>
```

there's a way to remove the repetition of `<a>` tags using JS ? so, the link becomes :

```
<a href="/page-example">Page Example</a>
```

Comment: How do you generate those links?

Comment: do you set the value of the `href` attribute by yourself or is that how this generator works like?

Comment: it automatically generates with the CMS because of an unknown bug

Comment: @MAZ The solution is to find that bug, not adjust the links on the client side. Please show us the code of the CMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at your url:

```
var url='<a href="<a href=&quot;/page-example&quot;>Page Example</a>">Page Example</a>';
```

First let's get rid of both occurences of `&quot;`

`url=url.replace(/&quot;/g,'');`

Now remove the first occurence of `</a>` by feeding the exact string instead of a regular expression to the `.replace` method.

```
url=url.replace('</a>','');
```

At this point your url looks like this:

`<a href="<a href=/page-example>Page Example">Page Example</a>`

We're getting closer. Let's remove anything in between the `>` and the `"` by

```
url=url.replace(/\>(.*)\"/,'"');
```

which gives us

`<a href="<a href=/page-example">Page Example</a>`

Almost done - finally let's get rid of `"<a href=`

`url=url.replace('"<a href=','"');`

To make the whole thing a bit more beautiful we can chain all four operations:

```js
var url = '<a href="<a href=&quot;/page-example&quot;>Page Example</a>">Page Example</a>';
url = url.replace(/&quot;/g, '').replace('</a>', '').replace(/\>(.*)\"/, '"').replace('"<a href=', '"');
console.log(url);
```

Comment: Glad I could help! =)

Answer (score 0):

Within your process you can use regex to extract the url from the href string:

```js
const string = "<a href=&quot;/page-example&quot;>Page Example</a>";
const url = string.match(/(\/)[\w-]*(?=&)/)[0];
console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the string split() function like this...

```
S='<a href=&quot;/page-example&quot;>Page Example</a>';

var A=split('&quot;');

document.write(A[1]);
```

This should display "/page-example", and you can then add it as the href to an anchor.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the `href`value that seems to be the correct A element and replace the incorrect one with the correct one:

```js
const a = document.querySelector('a[href]'); //if you have more <a> elements replace it to your need
const attr = a.getAttribute('href'); //get the value of 'href' attribute
const temp = document.createElement('template'); 
temp.innerHTML = attr;  //create the new A element from the 'href' attribute's value
const newA = temp.content.children[0]; //retrieve the new <a> element from the template
a.parentElement.replaceChild(newA, a); //replace the incorrect <a> element with the new one
```

```html
<a href="<a href=&quot;/page-example&quot;>Page Example</a>">Page Example</a>
```